# Problema con joins entre base de datos alumnos materias

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, join

Estoy estudiando los tipos de joins y realizando ejercicios, consigo hacer sin problema los inner joins pero, tengo dificultad con las demás variantes como el left join, en mi ejemplo tengo creada una base de datos pequeña y sencilla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos ingresados en las tablas:

**MATERIA1**

```
IDMATERIA1 | MATERIA1
-----------+-------------
1          | Ingles      
2          | Programacion 
3          | Matemáticas      
4          | Literatura 
5          | Algebra
```

**CARRERA1_MATERIA1**

```
ID        | IDCARRERA1 | IDMATERIA1
----------+------------+-----------
1         |   1        |   1   
2         |   1        |   2
3         |   1        |   3
4         |   2        |   1    
5         |   2        |   3
6         |   2        |   4
7         |   3        |   1   
8         |   3        |   3
9         |   3        |   4
10        |   2        |   5
```

**CARRERA1**

```
IDCARRERA1 | CARRERA1
-----------+---------------
1          | Sistemas          
2          | Administracion  
3          | Derecho
```

**ALUMNO1**

```
IDALUMNO1 | IDCARRERA1 | ALUMNO1
----------+------------+------------
1         | 1          | Jean Carlos    
2         | 2          | Maria
3         | 3          | Carla
```

Originalmente el ejercicio consiste en averiguar la carrera y las materias que tiene el alumno = Jean Carlos

Éste es el código que utilicé para unir las tablas y obtener lo que quería, con eso ya tengo las materias que el alumno está cursando:

```
select a.IDALUMNO1, a.ALUMNO1, m.MATERIA1 
from ALUMNO1 a 
     inner join CARRERA1 c on a.IDCARRERA1 = c.IDCARRERA1  
     inner join CARRERA1_MATERIA1 cm on cm.IDCARRERA1 = c.IDCARRERA1  
     inner join MATERIA1 m  on m.IDMATERIA1 = cm.IDMATERIA1 
where ALUMNO1='Jean Carlos'
```

Ahora necesito saber cuáles son las materias que NO está cursando, de acuerdo con mis registros no está cursando ni literatura ni álgebra, supuestamente al cambiar el inner por un left join iba a mostrar las materias que no tienen relación con mi alumno, pero no funciona, sigue apareciendo lo mismo.

¿Dónde está el problema y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: El operador `LEFT JOIN` devuelve todos los registros de la tabla a la izquierda del operador y adjunta los registros de la tabla de la derecha del operador que cumplan el filtro introducido, en caso de que no se cumpla el filtro, el operador introduce dichos registros (tabla derecha) a `NULL`. Es por eso por lo que en tu caso aparece el mismo resultado con `LEFT JOIN` que con `INNER JOIN`. Para solventar tu problema, deberias utilizar, en combinación con los `INNER JOIN` el operador `NOT IN`, aunque debes tener cuidado puesto que si el valor de `NOT IN` es `NULL`, siempre retornará `false`.

Comment: Te sugiero que pongas tu solución como respuesta para quien tenga tu misma duda, encuentre fácilmente la solución a la que llegaste. @jeancarlos733

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondiendo a mi propia pregunta la solución que encontré fue la siguiente:

```
select a.alumno1, m.materia1 
from materia1 m 
left join carrera1_materia1 cm on m.idmateria1 = cm.idmateria1 
left join carrera1 c on c.idcarrera1 = cm.idcarrera1 
left join alumno1 a on a.idalumno1 = c.idcarrera1 
where a.idalumno1 is null
```